# Margins for the whole slide in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, margins, presentations

I want to make a Beamer presentation with white margins at the edges, so the whole slide would be affected by these margins (including the color bars for my Berlin beaver theme, for example). So there would be a white frame around everything, kind of.
How can I do that? Is it possible at all?

So far what I've found affects only the text in the slide, but the color bars remain where they were, at the edges of the slide.
Just in case: I need different width for top/bottom margin (80px) and left/right (100px).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your explanation is very cryptic. Could you perhaps provide a MWE and a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top most layer drawn of a frame is the footline. You could add the margin to this layer, for example with a tikz picture. To have different line widths replace the rectangle with for individual lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[color=green, line width=0.2cm] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]